# Sum of Base-b Digit Sums of all Integers in Interval

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let $b > 1$ be an integer. Define $F_b : \mathbb{N}\cup \lbrace 0 \rbrace \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \cup \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ by $F_b(n)$ is the sum of the digits of ($n$ written in base $b$). For $m \in \mathbb{N}$, is there a formula for $G_b(m) = \sum \limits_{n=0}^{m} F_b(n)$?

For certain $m$ the problem is quite straight forward. When $b$ is even and $m = b^k-1$ for some $k \geq 1$, any number $n$ in $[0,m]$ with digits $n_{k-1}\cdots n_0$ (using leading zeroes if necessary) can be paired with its digitwise complement $\overline{n} := (b-1-n_{k-1})\cdots(b-1-n_0)$, which is another (distinct) number in $[0,m]$. We then have $F_b(n) + F_b(\overline{n}) = (b-1)k$, and so $G_b(b^k-1) = b^k(b-1)k/2$. When $b$ is odd, the integer with digits $((b-1)/2)\cdots((b-1)/2)$ is its own digitwise complement and is the only number with this property, and so $G_b(b^k-1) = (b^k-1)(b-1)k/2 + (b-1)k/2 = b^k(b-1)k/2$ as before.

For arbitrary $m$, one could let $b^k$ be the largest power of $b$ less than or equal to $m$ and write $G_b(m) = G_b(b^k-1) + [ G_b(m) - G_b(b^k-1)]$. The first term can be computed as above, but the second term $ G_b(m) - G_b(b^k-1)$ remains a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things work the same in every base, so I will take $b=10$.  You are correct that it is easy to handle the case when $m=10^k-1$, without depending on $b$ being even.  If you extend every number to $k$ digits with leading $0$s the sum of digits in the list does not change.  After you do, there are $10^k$ digits in each column, evenly distributed among the digits, so the digit sum of each column is $45 \cdot 10^{k-1}$ because the sum of all the digits from $0$ through $9$ is $45$.  The total digit sum is $k \cdot 45 \cdot 10^{k-1}.$

If $m$ is not of this form, write $m=a\cdot 10^k+b$ for $1 \le a \le 9$.  we can split the problem into the two ranges $0$ through $a \cdot 10^k-1$ and $a \cdot 10^k$ through $m$.  The first has $a$ copies of the run $0$ through $10^k-1$, each prefixed with a number from $0$ through $a-1$, so the sum is $a k\cdot 45 \cdot 10^{k-1} + \frac 12a(a-1)10^k$ where the second term comes from the first digits.  The final batch starting with $a$ has $b$ copies of $a$ plus all the numbers from $0$ through $b$, which gives $ab+G(b)$ and we have a recursive algorithm.

To calculate $G(m)$ write $m=a \cdot 10^k +b$.  We have $G(m)=a k\cdot 45 \cdot 10^{k-1} + \frac 12a(a-1)10^k+ab+G(b)$.  If $b \lt 10, G(b)=b$.  Since $b \lt m$ the process will terminate.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks!